# Configuring apache mod_proxy for cross-domain ajax calls

Tags: javascript, apache, api, mod-proxy

I started working on a small JavaScript app today that utilizes the Clipped API (http://clipped.me/api.html), but learned that there are cross-domain AJAX call issues, and the developer of the API didn't add support for JSONP. Here's the app itself:

```
var clippedAPI = "http://clipped.me/algorithm/clippedapi.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: clippedAPI,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        data: {
        url: "http://pandodaily.com/2013/03/26/y-combinator-demo-day-2013-still-looking-for- the-next-airbnb-or-dropbox/"}
    }).done(function(json) {
        console.log("JSON Data: " + json.title );
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
        console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
});
```

I've set up an Apache server on my Ubuntu machine, and have been suggested to use mod_proxy to set up a reverse proxy. The problem is that I just don't know how to do this -- this is my first time using Apache. I know all the basics like accessing my main Apache config files in Terminal. Can anyone give a noob a run-down on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Apache mod_proxy in Ubuntu

Setting up a reverse proxy using Apache in Ubuntu:

**1. Install reverse_proxy module**

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html
```

**2. Install libxml if it is not already installed.**

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

**3. Load the modules in apache2.conf file**

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule  headers_module       /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  deflate_module       /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadFile    /usr/lib/libxml2.so
```

4.Say you want to forward all requests starting  to **internal.server** then add the following to your apache2.conf file

```
# Disable proxy requests, using ProxyPass in vhost
ProxyRequests Off

# Block all requests
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Proxy>


<Proxy balancer://cluster>
        BalancerMember http://internal.server:802
        BalancerMember http://internal.server:801
        #below is to transfer sessions
        #ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic

</Proxy>


<Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

5.Hopes you are good to go.!

**update:**

```
sudo  aptitude download libxml2
sudo  ar -xf libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

**the following files will be extract from ubuntu package.

control.tar.gz data.tar.gz debian-binary libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4_amd64.deb**

```
# rm libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4_amd64.deb control.tar.gz
# tar xf data.tar.gz
# cd usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
# ls
```

**The following files will be there

libxml2.so.2 libxml2.so.2.7.8**

```
# mv * /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
# cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2* /usr/lib/
# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

- Starting web server apache2 [ OK ]

Comment: I think there's something wrong with libxml. I've tried to restart the server and I get the error "Cannot load /usr/lib/libxml2.so into server: /usr/lib/libxml2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"... I've checked that directory and it's true, I can't find libxml. I've tried installing twice. Any ideas?